# How to check the class conflict between the application server and WebSphere?

Tags: java, maven, websphere, classloader

I want to know whether any mechanisms /tools to check the same class conflicts between the jar files in my application server and Websphere.

**I have some of jar in** `/WEB_INF/lib`, class files in `/WEB_INF/classes` 
and also in `${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/plugins`. So how can I check whether the jar contain same classes ? Any tools available ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about traditional WebSphere (rather than Liberty), it sounds like you'd benefit from the **Class loader viewer** tool.

This can be helpful when unsure if you're loading a given class from some part of your application or some part of the runtime.  (I'm guessing when you ask about conflict between "the application server and WebSphere" you might mean conflict between "the application and WebSphere".)

This tool is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html) and  illustrated with some examples in sections 20.3, 20.4 in [this redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247971.pdf).

Comment: Didn't know about the answer from @Jarid.   That sounds easier and at least worth a try !

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that does precisely what you want - the migration binary scanner was updated to perform an "inventory" report that will check for duplicate classes within your app and potential conflicts with WebSphere libraries.  For more information, see this article: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/01/25/binary-scanner-not-just-migrations-anymore/